# SQL language differences between MSSQL 2000 and 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, backwards-compatibility

My company has an application developed for SQL Server 2005 (among others), and a potential client is attempting to install it on SQL Server 2000.  Naturally, installation failed.  Specifically, it failed with syntax errors in our CREATE TABLE statements.

Is there a summary of the language differences between these two databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the list of breaking changes [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143532(SQL.90).aspx) at technet.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no summary of Transact SQL changes from 2000 to 2005. There are a few [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623139) that take a detailed look at the changes but I wouldn't call them a summary.

For a more immediate answer to your client's problem you could try comparing the specifications for the [2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255(SQL.80).aspx) and [2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(SQL.90).aspx)  versions of the CREATE TABLE function.